# What does this means $| + ; \hat{x}\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation

I know that the $+$ means spin up and that $\hat{x}$ is the position operator but I don't undestand the meaning of this two sign together in the same bra (like this $| + ; \hat{x}\rangle$ )?

Comment: We don't know, either. Check the source/ ask the lecturer...

Comment: I think it means that $\sigma_x|+; \hat{x}\rangle = +1 |+;\hat{x}\rangle$...

Comment: @ValterMoretti While this seems plausible, it could also mean something like $|x\rangle \otimes |+\rangle$. We can only guess here...

Comment: $\hat{x}$ or $x$?

Comment: x with a hat but after  more than 50 minutes of looking for the meaning. I ve found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i ve finally found the answer:
[image]

Comment: wacky notation.

Comment: It is my guess...

Comment: It’s not “wacky”, and this is an equality but not the definition. As Valter explained in a comment, the notation means “spin ‘up’ along the $x$-axis”.